# need help to display value in a form for html

Tags: python, html

I need to display the value that was entered in a form after the user clicks the submit button. It displays it for a split second but when the page reloads it's gone

```
<html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='main.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
<title> Patent Info </title>
<form action="" method="POST" >
  Enter Room Number <input type="number" name="getInput" id="data" min="1" max="5">
  <input type="submit" onclick="c.value = getInput.value">    
  <h4>Going to Room: <output name="c"></output></h4> 
</form>
```

```
   from flask import Flask, render_template, request
   from random import randrange

   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route("/")
   def main():
   return render_template('index.html')

   @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
  def my_form_post():
  input_nopol = request.form['getInput']
  if request.method == 'POST':
   with open('nopol.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(input_nopol))
   return render_template('index.html', nopol=input_nopol)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

I know i can do it if i change from type submit to type button but then my POST method dose not work

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<h4>Going to Room: <output name="c">{{ nopol }}</output></h4>
```

Comment: but it will not display i think becouse you have to store data in database

Answer (score 0):

Just add this below  `<h4>Going to Room: <output name="c"></output></h4>`
`<p>{{ nopol }}</p>`